# command grep troubleshooting

Tags: linux, shell, command-line, grep

I have the following task from school: 
List all the lines from the file find_config, who starts with etc.
I put this command in:

[image: command line]

the problem is that I see from that file (find_config) that it has 12 times etc somewhere.
But I want only to get the 2 first as an output ....
What did I do wrong. I already have ^ before the etc, so it should work.
Hopefully you can help me out.

Best regards
Abdi

Comment: The lines you want appear to start with `/etc`, not `etc`

Comment: Hi! It would be best of you posted the contents of your screenshot as text instead.

Answer (score 2):

You did nothing wrong: `^etc` indeed asks grep to only print lines
that start with `etc`, and your file appears to contain no such line,
which explains the empty output.

If, instead, you meant to search for lines starting with `/etc`, you
would have to write:

```
grep '^/etc'
```